# Would this source of code be "Safe" from SQL injections?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

Would the following source of code be safe from SQL injections? If not, would you please provide a way to make it more secure?

Please note: Database credentials were hidden for security while making this post.

PHP Version: 7.0

```
    <?php
    try{
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hidden', 'hidden', 'hidden');
        //**$handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $myID = 8869935;
    $query = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM Calls WHERE UserID=:cid');
    $query->bindParam(':cid', $myID);
    $query->execute();

    while($row = $query->fetch()){
        echo $row['CallerID'], '<br>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: I have completely changed the question as the last one was not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to tell if this is safe from SQL injection vulnerabilities:

The query string has no PHP variables concatenated with it:

```
$handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM Calls WHERE UserID=:cid');
```

This is just a string, with no PHP variables or PHP constants. It's a fixed string, and nothing is modifying it before it is given to the prepare() function. This is enough to guarantee it's safe from SQL injection.

There's no way the bind variables for the query parameter can introduce SQL injection. The query is parsed by the RDBMS *before* bind variables are combined. There is no way an SQL injection can modify the query *after* the query is parsed.